# PyQt - saving the states of all objects to a file and then load them?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a gui with different kinds of qt objects such as QListWidget, QLineEdit and QComboBox.

What would be the best way to save all of the current settings to a file (by clicking a Push Button for example) and then load them? (after closing and reopening the gui and press another Push Button to load).

Thanks!

Comment: So all i have to do is create a QSettings object and it would automatically save all of the settings and valued for me? Also, what if i want to save multiple settings in multiple files and have the user able to browse through his computer and load his a specific file?

Comment: No, you have to add all the data you want to save to the `QSettings` manually, and then re-apply it to the GUI manually.

Comment: Could i save python internal data structures such as a dictionary? And would that files thing i mentioned be possible?

Comment: Generally, anything that can be serialized (using `pickle` or `json`) can be saved.

Comment: Okay i'll try it, thanks!